# Get A wrestling dummy filled or unfilled

Tags: sparring, equipment, grappling, wrestling, mixed-martial-arts

I don't know whether to get a filled/unfilled dummy/hangman. I've done a bit of limited research so I'm going to list the pros and cons I've heard about each. BTW This isn't a "Shopping Recommendation" request - I just want to know what will be better.

**Unfilled Dummy:**

- Pros:

  - Most look cooler
  - Adjustable weight
  - Cheaper (not including stuffing)
- Cons:

  - Might break easily
  - May take along time to assemble

**Filled Dummy:**

- Pros:

  - Stronger
  - Can use it straight away
  - Better for strikes
- Cons:

  - Limbs not as flexible for submissions
  - More expensive

So what should I get? I don't want to spend more than £100 and a lot of filled ones don't ship to the UK.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Could you define what you men by "better"?  What are your criterion?

Comment: This isn't a shopping list request, I just want help shopping??? What is your definition of a shopping question?

Answer (score 1):

In general either has it's plus/minuses as you mentioned.  I personally like the more durable filled ones.  It requires greater strength and impacts than light ones, but is more similar to an actual person with weight instead of lighter with techniques only.  You might start with a unfilled and work to a filled one, but I think to truly practice for real situations a heavier filled one is more realistic.

If you goal is more for competition or demonstration the unfilled might work better here.  As your end goal is not 100% clear it's more generic here.  My vote is filled though for a serious person as it will pay off in the end with training and should last longer, even if it takes longer to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you value your equipment quality?

There's a reason these dummies are so expensive; professionals are REALLY good at making them. You risk damaging your expensive dummy if it's not filled properly. They are incredibly dense for a reason - structural integrity.

Order your dummies and bags filled. If you can't afford it, save your pennies. It's worth it.